# jquery gallery with ajax loading of images in the background?

Tags: jquery, gallery

Is there any jquery library or plugin which is able to load external images in the background and show a preview loading gif?

It should also support scrollbars for viewing images that are much larger than the current resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the jQuery Cycle Plugin before. It supports a preview loading picture and preload the pictures. It has many nice features. I'm not sure if you can control the height/witdh but I think if you put a css overflow property on a surrounding div.

For instance using the some small modifications to the Basic Demo which you can find on 
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html

In this case it is only the CSS style I have changed :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .slideshow { height: 160px; width: 160px; margin: auto; overflow: auto }
        .slideshow img { }
    </style>
    <!-- include jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See more on their homepage:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/